# Run a select based on an if condition

Tags: oracle

Prior to posting this question, I have looked at case when, but it doesn't solve my problem.

The scenario is, based on whether it is a Monday in the week, I need to fetch some data from a table. I can write it in PL/SQL block, but I want to achieve this in plain SQL.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: To expand on this a little bit, this is what I want to do - check if the curdate is Monday, then select * from another_table. Is this possible in SQL alone?

Answer (score 0):

`to_char(sysdate-3, 'DAY')` will return `MONDAY` you can trim it and using `decode` return different value than `null`:

```
select decode(TRIM(to_char(sysdate-3, 'DAY')),'MONDAY', 1, null) from dual
```

**EDIT:**

In where you can

```
where decode(to_char(sysdate-3, 'fmDAY'), 'MONDAY', 1, null) =1
```

*`sysdate-3` was choose because it's Thursday today

Comment: `to_char(sysdate-3, 'fmDAY')` works also instead of TRIM.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tables have the same structure this would work:

```
select * from table1
where to_char(sysdate, 'DY') = 'MON'
union all
select * from table2
where to_char(sysdate, 'DY') != 'MON'
```

Using day literals like this is dependent on your NLS settings. So adjust the solution if you need to.